# Android: cannot import BaseGameUtils successfully in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I want to use game api in my android project.

And I get started by following the instructions described in Google Site
(the part - Setting up your game project) from the following link.
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

I have downloaded the library **BaseGameUtils** from this link
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples

Then I import it as a project as described in instruction.

However, what I've got is a project named **main** but not **BaseGameUtils**.

And then I cannot called its **BaseGameActivity** in my android project.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

When importing project, not to select BaseGameUtils folder, but the root folder 'android-samples-master'. Then check the project named BaseGameUtils.

Comment: This does not help me, whereas @SEG.Veenstra answer helped!

Answer (score 3):

Same issue solved differently.

I've imported the **BaseGameUtils** project and also couldn't refer to it.
If you right-click the **BaseGameUtils** project that you've just imported and then go to **properties > android** and check **"is library"** you are able to refer to it in your app project.

Comment: Thx this worked! There seems to be very little support on the web for this stuff, kinda sucks.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Download code from github,  https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples
In the downloaded folder copy the files from

android-basic-samples-master\BasicSamples\libraries\BaseGameUtils\src\main\java

to

android-basic-samples-master\BasicSamples\libraries\BaseGameUtils\src\main\src

Now import android-basic-samples-master as an android project.

Choose only BaseGameUtils , you'll get a project called main, right click project > properties > android
Add library and select google-play-services_lib and also tick isLibrary and OK.

Also add an external jar android-support-v4.jar by right clicking project > properties > Java Build Path > Add external Jar .

Now add this project named main to your actual project as a library.  TADA !

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED.

You must follow: **From the command line run Scripts/make_eclipse_compat (or Scripts/make_eclipse_compat.cmd on Windows). This creates the directory structure needed to import the projects correctly.**
Attention: android-basic-samples-master > Script/make_eclipse_compat.cmd

Ref: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

Answer (score 0):

Adding to SEG.Veenstra's answer "....just imported and then go to properties > android and check "is library" you are able to refer to it in your app project" this link as there are problems in Google's documentation: [Android Play Services Leaderboard cannot be installed (BaseGameUtils)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442525/android-play-services-leaderboard-cannot-be-installed-basegameutils)

Answer (score 0):

This is the original Directory structure from this playgameservices github [link](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples)

android-basic-samples->BasicSamples->libraries->BaseGameUtils->

[image]

Change your BaseGameUtils project directory structure to this:

[image]

1. Now try importing this BaseGameUtils project into your Eclipse workspace.
2. Right Click on BaseGameUtils project->properties->Android->Check Is Library
3. Right Click on "YourProject"->properties->Android->Add->BaseGameUtils

Apply & OK.

Now BaseGameUtils is linked with your project