# Android Play Services Leaderboard cannot be installed (BaseGameUtils)

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard

I follow https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init to setup leaderboards. So in my game project I have setup google_play_services lib as it already uses AdMob. Now I need to all Also BaseGameUtils. But the steps in section "Setting up your game project" in the link above don't work. Let me tell what I have done:

1. Opened https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples and pressed "Download ZIP".
2. Extracted the zip and imported the folder into my project. Disselected all and selected only `BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main` which was added in my project as `main` and not as `BaseGameUtils`.
3. Right clicked on `main` project, in `Properties->Android` section selected `Is Library` and in my game project in `Properties->Android` section added Reference to `main` library. (Note that if you don't select `Is Library` you cannot do `6. In the Library panel, click the Add button. 7.Select BaseGameUtils.`step as it is pointed out in the tutorial )
4. In my package src directory create a new class like this:

> ```
> import gms.common.api.*;
>
> import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;
>
> public class MyGameActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
> ```

but neither of the imports is recognized. How to setup this? This should have been to be so easy but is it so creapy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The steps are incomplete in the tutorial. Here are the actual steps:

1. Opened https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples and pressed "Download ZIP" or you can clone the git repo too.
2. Then there is a `Scripts/make_eclipse_compat` (.cmd for Windows) script. `cd android-basic-samples;` and run the script. It generates `eclipse_compat` next to `Scripts` dir.
3. Import into eclipse `android-basic-samples/eclipse_compat/libraries/BaseGameUtils` and not the original `BaseGameUtils` downloaded. Note that in this case in Eclipse you are not getting add there `main` project but a project called `BaseGameUtils`.
4. Right click on `BaseGameUtils` project go to `Properties->Android` and make sure `Is Library` is checked and add `google_play_services` as Reference library.
5. If you use for example Facebook SDK or other SDKs then you may have such a conflict:

> Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list, but
>   not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1........

Here is the resolution: [Facebook SDK for Android duplicate support library on dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517222/facebook-sdk-for-android-duplicate-support-library-on-dependencies)

6. Also

   import gms.common.api.*;

is wrong you should do this:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.*;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;


public class MyGameActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
```

Answer (score 0):

For MAC users.

Open Terminal.

cd *android-basic-samples*

then type **bash Scripts/make_eclipse_compat**

It will generate **eclipse_compat folder** next to the Scripts folder. Import to Eclipse the generated folder.